# Error permission for Write in path with Ansible

Tags: python, ansible

I am trying to install a monitoring agent using ansible with the `win_command` module to run by CMD as an administrator, Everyone I am having permission problems in the folder, but already set it to 'Everyone' and with Read and Write privileges

**Playbook:**

```
 - name: Installing SD Agent
    win_command: cmd.exe -
    args: 
      stdin: start /wait {{ DIRWIN }}\SD_AGENT_WINNT\setup.exe  /w /z"/sf{{ DIRWIN }}\SD_AGENT_WINNT\NTX64_Silent_Install.txt" /s  /f2"\INSTALLSD\Silent_SD.log"
    become: yes
    become_user: administrador
    register: installSD

  - debug: var=installSD
```

**Output:**

```
TASK [Automation_Install_SD : debug] *********************************************************************************************ok: [192.168.149.6] => {
    "installSD": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "cmd.exe -",
        "delta": "0:00:23.032349",
        "end": "2020-03-02 04:53:09.762995",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2020-03-02 04:52:46.730645",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "Microsoft Windows [versão 10.0.14393]\r\n(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.\r\n\r\nC:\\Users\\Administrador.WIN-C7S8PFMJMUD>start /wait {{ DIRWIN }}\SD_AGENT_WINNT\setup.exe  /w /z"/sf{{ DIRWIN }}\SD_AGENT_WINNT\NTX64_Silent_Install.txt" /s  /f2"\INSTALLSD\Silent_SD.log"\r\n\r\nC:\\Users\\Administrador.WIN-C7S8PFMJMUD>",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "Microsoft Windows [versão 10.0.14393]",
            "(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.",
            "",
            "C:\\Users\\Administrador.WIN-C7S8PFMJMUD>start /wait {{ DIRWIN }}\SD_AGENT_WINNT\setup.exe  /w /z"/sf{{ DIRWIN }}\SD_AGENT_WINNT\NTX64_Silent_Install.txt" /s  /f2"\INSTALLSD\Silent_SD.log"",
            "",
            "C:\\Users\\Administrador.WIN-C7S8PFMJMUD>"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Log:**

```
03-02-2020 13:34:33: RC_INFO: The C:\AGENT\SD directory has locked files, you cannot continue.
```

**Variable:**

```
DIRWIN = C:\AGENT\SD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add specifically these configurations in your playbook (these are the configurations I see you're missing):

```
become_method: runas
ansible_become_password: "{{ password }}"
```

By Ansible [official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html):

```
- name: copy a file from a fileshare with custom credentials
  win_copy:
    src: \\server\share\data\file.txt
    dest: C:\temp\file.txt
    remote_src: yes
  vars:
    ansible_become: yes
    ansible_become_method: runas
    ansible_become_user: DOMAIN\user
    ansible_become_password: Password01
    ansible_become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
```